# excel data to datagridview through dataset using OLE skips the initial blank rows and blank columns

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset, connection-string, oledb

I am using OLE related API's for reading data to DataSet and later to view in DataGridView. The source is an excel file. If the first row or column is empty than that row or column is getting skipped. I wish to read the data irrespective of empty/has data. Other rows/columns even if its empty its working fine, but only starting is missing.

I read about ColumnHeader and tried changing connectionString (HDR=NO) and others but nothing worked out.

Any additional things need to be specified while calling the API?  One to one mapping with the excel column and the DataGridView column is missing because of skipping this initial blank rows/columns.

Anything needs to be added/modified to this OleDbDataAdapter parameter, which actually reads the data and fills to dataset:

```
    OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(
                    "select * from [" + worksheetName + "$]", con);
```

Yes, I am setting some required information and calling a method to read data from each sheet. I am not doing any action on the rows/columns except reading them.

```
    OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);

    System.Data.DataTable getWorksheetData(OleDbConnection con, OleDbDataAdapter cmd)
    {
        con.Open();
        System.Data.DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();

        cmd.Fill(excelDataSet);
        con.Close();

        return excelDataSet.Tables[0];
    }
```

My connection string is:

```
    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + 
        fileName + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;Mode=Read;ReadOnly=True;\"";
```

Comment: For some reason i had the same problem, i however just started working with cells directly with out the OLE queries, i have given it 1 up out of interest, for the reason it does not work.

Comment: can you share the whole code on how did you get all the data from excel?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks John for reminding me.

Comment: @spajce, it was midnight when I posted this query. Morning I have added the remaining part of the related code.

Comment: try to use the `DefaultView` something like → `excelDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView`

Comment: I don't think this setting will work. The default itself is the data what it has retreived. This can be applied for further filtering of the retrieved data. Ex: excelDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = xxxx_condition.